# incomingmessages not received by broker and mqttclient but in wireshark its present

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, wireshark

problem is that im not receiving messages from mqtt client running on a device.
i have a hardware device. on this device there is a mqtt client.
what i did:
i connected this device with laptop running mqtt broker mosquito and jmeter with mqtt plugin as client listening on 1883 port.

i tried: i have added rules in windows firewall for inbound and outbound opened port 1883.
now if i check in wireshark on laptop i see device sending messages to connect broker. from ipadress of device connect messages sent to ipadress of laptop at port 1883. it was expected that broker will send messages back to device but as no messages received by broker so no messages sent from broker to device.
neither i get messages in jmeter subscriber.

i tried: i installed mqtt client "mqttlens" locally on laptop. connection tested with broker and it works. so broker is ok.
can someone help

Comment: Difficult to help without a lot more detail; perhaps you have subscribed to the wrong topic? Please edit your question and provide detailed info e.g. what are you seeing in Wireshark (copy/paste the data into your question), what broker are you using, what is shown in the broker logs (add these to your question), what 'mqtt client' did you install and how did you use this to test?

Comment: So with mqttlens you are successfully receiving messages from the device? Just knowing you can connect does not really help much i'd suggest enabling logging in mosquito; that will let you know if it is receiving the messages.

Comment: no its not like that. mqttlens i installed on laptop to test broker. i m listening to topics in mqttlens subscriber but no messages comin in